# haproxy cofiguration getting error

Tags: haproxy

```
 service haproxy start 
 * Starting haproxy haproxy
[ALERT] 299/163851 (6382) : Starting proxy 50.112.164.38:80: cannot bind socket
[ALERT] 299/163851 (6382) : Starting proxy 50.112.164.38:443: cannot bind socket
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that there is no listen port in the configuration. use "listen" or "bind" and then restart it. It should work. If you still having trouble show the code over here and I will look into it

Safi